# HTML draw arrows behind text

Tags: html, html5-canvas, jcl

**Can html5 canvas do the following? If yes, how...**

1. Be places behind bottom layer place behind HTML text
2. Can you accurately find the coordinates specified HTML texts (perhaps identified with `span` ID) regardless the of browser zoom size, or line wrap

**I am trying to create the following with HTML/CSS/JS:**

[image: html highlight image]
(please excuse the green squiggly underlines)

The highlighted text could obviously be set with `background-color:`

The tricky part is connecting the highlighted text with arrows, I would think it might be able to be done with HTLM canvas, but I am open to any ideas.

Also nice little bonus would be the have highlighting/arrows appear on hover or maybe on off button.

PS a little background, the text is some simplified JCL (sort of scripting language for Mainframes) and the highlighted items are files.  I am attempting to make it easier to trace the data flow through a job (script).  This is pretty simple version but many jobs can be 100s of lines long with lot details that make it hard to trace the which steps related to each other.  If there other ideas or tools to help trace the data flow in JCL let me know.

```
//COBLPGM  EXEC PGM=COBLPGM
//INPUT    DD DSN=&&SORT,DISP=(OLD,DELETE)
//NACHA    DD DSN=NODE.OPER.COBLPGM.OUT(+1)

//SORT2    EXEC PGM=SORT
//SORTIN   DD DSN=NODE.OPER.COBLPGM.OUT(+1)
//SORTOUT  DD DSN=&&SORT2,DISP=(,PASS)
//SYSIN    DD DSN=NODE.OPER.PROCLIB(MEM)

//UNRELATE EXEC PGM=UNPGM
//INPUT    DD DSN=NODE.OPER.UNRELATED.FILE
//REPORT   DD DSN=&&REPORT

//TSTEMPT1 EXEC PGM=SPOPNCLO
//IN       DD DSN=&&SORT2,DISP=(OLD,DELETE)

//    IF TSTEMPT1.RC=0 THEN

//SORT3    EXEC PGM=SORT
//SORTIN   DD DSN=NODE.OPER.COBLPGM.OUT(+1)
//SORTOUT  DD DSN=&&SORT3,DISP=(,PASS),LRECL=141
//SYSIN    DD DSN=NODE.OPER.CNTRLCDS(PARM)

//    ENDIF
```

Comment: The question as it stands is too broad. Try to narrow it down to something more specific like how to draw line/arrows on a canvas, or how to find coordinates of text position, etc. Even break it up in several questions if necessary.

Comment: I didn't want to box anyone into a specific solution if a more elegant solution exists that I didn't think of (perhaps a JS library or different approach show the dataflow)

Comment: For what purpose? What about PROCs? What about INCLUDEs? What about backward references (see references, backward)? What about symbols, and where they are set? Have you talked to your scheduler people? Why do you have JOBs which are hundreds of lines long? The computer can always grasp them. We make them smaller, so we can. Where do coloured arrows come into it? And they're not files, they're datasets. As well as broad, it's tool suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a "conceptual" answer showing that you can track HTML to synchronize a canvas element.

The following code has the text itself in a `<pre>` tag in HTML. There is a canvas in the background set with fixed size. The canvas is updated on scrolling so the boxes are drawn relative to page (it should also be updated on resize, not shown).

As we can track the text you can see we would also be able to place any other graphics relative to it as well such as arrows and lines. I have not shown this here as I feel it would be too broad, but you should get the gist of it as it shows how to calculate the text line and char positions.

**The basis is:**

- Get absolute position of the `<pre>` tag
- Count number of lines (be careful to place text right after the tag and not on a new line, as well as placing end-tag at the same line as the last text-line)
- Dividing absolute height on number of lines will give the line-height in pixels for each line
- Use `measureText()` of context to measure the width of each line by setting context to use the same font and size as the `<pre>` tag
- Use the rectangle from previous pre-tag to offset x and y for the line position.
- Each char is calculate using the chars preceding the current, with measureText() (cell being this position and that of the next char).

The text is kept selectable with the canvas marking areas in the background.

Note that special chars in the text-line may throw off measureText (such as && in the example text). These chars must be encoded or replaced before measuring. Replacing is not a problem with a monospaced font such as in this case.

## Demo

```js
var pre = document.querySelector("pre"),          // get pre ele,ent
    rect = pre.getBoundingClientRect(),           // get its absolute position
    lines = pre.innerHTML.split("\n"),            // split text lines
    count = lines.length,                         // count lines
    lineH = rect.height / count,                  // line height
    
    canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),    // setup canvas
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;                 // todo: update on resize
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

ctx.font = "14px monospace";                      // use same font in canvas as for pre
ctx.strokeStyle = "#d00";
ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);                          // makes lines sharper for demo

window.onscroll = drawBoxes;                      // we need to track scrolling
drawBoxes();

function drawBoxes() {                            // render line boxes (y)
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var w = ctx.measureText(lines[i]).width;
    if (w) ctx.strokeRect(rect.left, rect.top + i * lineH - window.scrollY, w, lineH - 1);
    showChars(lines[i], rect.top + i * lineH - window.scrollY, lineH); 
  }
}
function showChars(line, y, h) {                  // render char lines (x)
  ctx.beginPath();
  for(var i = 0, ch, x, s = ""; ch = line[i]; i++) {
    s += ch;
    x = ctx.measureText(s).width;
    ctx.moveTo(x, y); ctx.lineTo(x, y + h - 1);
  }
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
}
```

```css
canvas {position:fixed;left:0;top:0;z-index:-1}
pre {font:14px monospace}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<pre>//COBLPGM  EXEC PGM=COBLPGM
//INPUT    DD DSN=SORT,DISP=(OLD,DELETE)
//NACHA    DD DSN=NODE.OPER.COBLPGM.OUT(+1)

//SORT2    EXEC PGM=SORT
//SORTIN   DD DSN=NODE.OPER.COBLPGM.OUT(+1)
//SORTOUT  DD DSN=SORT2,DISP=(,PASS)
//SYSIN    DD DSN=NODE.OPER.PROCLIB(MEM)

//UNRELATE EXEC PGM=UNPGM
//INPUT    DD DSN=NODE.OPER.UNRELATED.FILE
//REPORT   DD DSN=REPORT

//TSTEMPT1 EXEC PGM=SPOPNCLO
//IN       DD DSN=SORT2,DISP=(OLD,DELETE)

//    IF TSTEMPT1.RC=0 THEN

//SORT3    EXEC PGM=SORT
//SORTIN   DD DSN=NODE.OPER.COBLPGM.OUT(+1)
//SORTOUT  DD DSN=SORT3,DISP=(,PASS),LRECL=141
//SYSIN    DD DSN=NODE.OPER.CNTRLCDS(PARM)

//    ENDIF</pre>
```